# Use Hapi server with React-Flux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, flux, hapi.js

I have a React-Flux application on which i use React-Router to transit between pages. I was using watchify and broserify to load my index.html. My app.js is where I require all the react-components created and specify the routes.

**index.html:**

```
<body>
    <section id="app-container"></section>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js:**

```
var React = require('react');
var Persistence = require('./utils/Persistence');
var App = require('./components/App.react');
var reactRouter = require('react-router');

var PickingRequestProcessingPage = require('./components/PickingRequestProcessingPage.react');
var PickingRequestItemsListingPage = require('./components/PickingRequestItemsListingPage.react');
var PickingRequestsListingPage = require('./components/PickingRequestsListingPage.react');
var DoubleCheckerPage = require('./components/DoubleCheckerPage.react');
var LoginPage = require('./components/LoginPage.react');
var ErrorPage = require('./components/ErrorPage.react');

// Loads Mock API
Persistence.startAppMockData();

// Renders App Controller View


React.render(
    (
        <reactRouter.Router>

            <reactRouter.Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
            <reactRouter.Route path="/requests" component={PickingRequestsListingPage} />
            <reactRouter.Route path="/review/:pickingRequestId" component={PickingRequestItemsListingPage} />
            <reactRouter.Route path="/processing/:pickingRequestId" component={PickingRequestProcessingPage} />
            <reactRouter.Route path="/doublecheck" component={DoubleCheckerPage} />
            <reactRouter.Route path="/error" component={ErrorPage} />


        </reactRouter.Router>

    ), document.getElementById('app-container')
);
```

What is the proper way to create the routes in order to load the app on localhost with Hapi?